# @nuxtjs/auth-next doesn't consume the token returned by cognito

Tags: oauth-2.0, nuxt.js, amazon-cognito, nuxt-auth

I am having a problem with the [@nuxtjs/auth-next](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/) module for connecting via Cognito. It does send me to my cognito login portal and redirects me with to my app with my token value, and type.

However the module doesn't consume it, it doesnt say that I am logged in and doesn't fetch the user info.

Here is my `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
strategies: {
  awsCognito: {
    scheme: 'oauth2',
    endpoints: {
      authorization: 'https://***********************/login',
      token: 'https://***********************/oauth2/token',
      userInfo: 'https://***********************/oauth2/userInfo',
      logout: 'https://***********************/logout'
    },
    token: {
      property: 'access_token',
      type: 'Bearer',
      required: true,
      maxAge: 3600
    },
    refreshToken: {
      property: 'refresh_token',
      maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30
    },
    user: {
      property: true,
      autoFetch: true,
      propertyName: false
    },
    responseType: 'token',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/callback',
    logoutRedirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    clientId: '******************',
    scope: ['email', 'openid'],
    codeChallengeMethod: 'S256'
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this config match what you do see in the network tab response?

Comment: I am getting this in the params which looks ok ? /login?response_type=token&client_id=34jk2rvmg29fkm7nvh6522m63n&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/callback&scope=email openid&state=0SJ9ur68l0&code_challenge_method=S256&nonce=jSJZyo1hNp&code_challenge=OpeHXMlfmdjHW3eXzFWE_VNm6qF_4i3DC6DXixWPy8Y

Comment: Not sure of the actual thing. Please edit your question rather than posting it inline here, it's not really readable.